# EF6 Code First: When does EF magic populate collection after parent relation set?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-first

In earlier EF, in a *1-parent : many-child* relation, if the parent reference is set on the child, then the child is also added to the parent's collection of children. This isn't the same in code first?

Using the example below, one parent **Entry** can have many child **FindKey**s:

```
EfTestModel eft = new EfTestModel();
Entry en = eft.Entries.First();        //Get an entry to work with
int cnt1 = en.FindKeys.Count();   //=0  en's FindKeys collection is empty

FindKey fk = eft.FindKeys.Create();    //Create new entity with proxies
fk.Entry = en;                         //Set the parent relation
//other fields updated here

int cnt2 = en.FindKeys.Count();   //=0  en's FindKeys collection still empty
eft.FindKeys.Add(fk);                  //Add the new FindKey to the context
int cnt3 = en.FindKeys.Count();   //=1  fk now added to FindKeys collection
```

Why is cnt2=0 instead of 1, since parent relation was set?  cnt3=1: why does adding it to the context populate the **FindKey**s set? Is there a manual way to trigger the relational magic?

If I'm updating rather than adding a new **FindKey** (therefore *.Add(fk)* can't be called) is there another way to populate the relations and therefore make sure all the relations are correct?